# Select2 4.0.1 CSS of Drop-Down doesn't seem to work (different width compared to select)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2, dropdown

i'm trying to resolve another problem with the new select2 4.0.1. What i am trying to achieve is to change default width of a drop-down when opened.

Here is a the screen with select 2.3.x working as expected.

[image]

Here is a working JS BIN how it works (or doesn't work) with select2 4.0.1

http://jsbin.com/dujakenusi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

In 2.3.x version, there was an attribute *dropdownAutoWidth* which seems to not work now. I've found some articles here on SO about *width: 'resolve'*, but it doesn't work as well.

Any help? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Finally.

The answer is this CSS:

```
.select2-results__option[aria-selected] {
white-space: nowrap;
max-width: 320px;}
```

which sets the style to `<li>` element of a *dropdown*. i've removed dropDownCSS and *width* attributes from  the *select2* initialization as they weren't used.

http://jsbin.com/rixedobohe/edit?html,css,js,console,output